Carbon Footprint Quantification (ISO updates)
How do we compute the carbon footprint for an item?  One option is to follow the methodology outlined in ISO 14067.  It appears that that standard was first drafted in 2013 and that standards are reviewed every five years.  That led to an updated ISO 14067:2018 in 2018.  I would have expected to see a 14067:2023 version last year, but I can't find it and only see some hints that this review was abandoned in February.
What's going on?  I'd like to use the most up-to-date standard but it seems like I'm missing something.

PS: I'm new to this site-- if this question would be more appropriate elsewhere, I'd really appreciate any suggestions as to where I should ask it.
